MSB4018 Error on Every Second Build: System.Text.Json Not Found and Empty .deps.json File
I'm working on a C++/CLI project in Visual Studio 2019 (32-bit target platform) using .NET SDK 6.0.135. This project runs on a build server and has a dependency on System.Text.Json, although it's not explicitly referenced as a NuGet package. The build fails every other time with the following error:
Error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Additional details from the advanced log show that System.Text.Json is missing in the .deps.json directory or that the .deps.json file is empty, causing this error. However, the error only appears on every second build.
Additional Observation: A colleague noticed that, whenever the error occurs, the build process attempts to load one of the following:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/System.Text.Json.dll
C:/Program Files/dotnet/sdk/6.0.135/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/tools/net472/System.Text.Json.dll
Both of these assemblies are version 4.x, but the build requires version 6.0.0.0. However, if the .deps.json file was not deleted, it correctly uses the version of System.Text.Json from the 6.0.135 SDK, and the build succeeds.
What I've treid so far:

Cleaning and manually deleting the bin and obj directories — no lasting fix, the problem persists every other build.

Comparing with a working setup on another machine (with .NET SDK 6.0.133), where this error doesn’t appear — no significant differences found.

Enabling assembly binding logging — reveals that System.Text.Json and other dependencies are being loaded under the .NET Framework environment, which fails due to compatibility issues.



Have exactly the same problem after upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 16.11.41 from 16.11.31. Had to downgrade a NetCore 6.0 project to NetCoreApp3.1. But it will not compile with the same errormessage as you..

The question seems to contain a hint for a workaround that worked for me, so many thanks!
The issue seems to be specific to sdk 6.0.135.
I've had exactly same setup as the topic starter on my local machine and run into exact same issue. Furthermore it started to show up on any(!) project, even blank VS2019 console hello world template (targeting net5.0).

I removed the 6.0.135 sdk installation and console app would work, yet my original app targeting 6.0 was obviously unhappy
I reinstalled 6.0.135 and the problem re-appeared
I removed 6.0.135 and installed 6.0.133
=> it works and suits me

Also my colleague having 6.0.131 on his machine saw no trouble.
Update with more info:

6.0.135 is a security update released on October 8th 2024; .NET SDKs get auto-updated so this is how it 'breaks'
for those wanting to disable auto updates of .NET SDK here's how to do that: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-updates-coming-to-microsoft-update/
reminder that dotnet --list-sdks is a useful command for checking .NET SDKs installed


Ah, I'm seeing now 6.0.135 is a a security patch released on October 8, 2024 - few days ago; I didn't realize it was auto-updating for me

Thank you so much for posting this.  For me I also had two versions of .NET 6, one which was installed with VS and one that was installed manually, and it looks like at least in my case there might have been a conflict between the two also and I could only have one or the other installed.  Haven't verified that at all with wider testing than my own machine, but interesting data.
